# Can Kusto string column store a tab character?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Can a Kusto string datatype contain tab character? I am asking this since we are trying to export data to external table with TSV as its format. So I am trying to assess if there can be a situation where a string column of a table being queried for exporting to external table can contain a tab character. If so , the export will not be any good , the export itself might succeed but the data won't be readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Kusto strings are stored in UTF-8, so tabs are definitely supported.

Here's a quick test in Kusto Explorer:

[image]

Comment: So what is the way around this if we are exporting data to an external table defined as a TSV ? Another alternative is CSV but that is very poor choice as our data can contain lot of commas. Defining the external table as parquet etc. would involve additional processing so it can slow down export , which is critical if the data being exported is huge.

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do with the exported data afterwards. If you plan to query it using external tables, then parquet would definitely be the best choice for you, and you shouldn't worry about the exporting performance (in fact, we'll soon roll out a significant improvement in perf of export to parquet).

Comment: Tab characters are replaced with spaces when exporting to TSV.

Comment: @yifats that's exactly the issue I am facing -- I am exporting as TSV to an external table and when I try to get count of the external table from Kusto I get an error even though export itself succeeds without any error. If tabs are being replaced when spaces when exporting why am I getting this error I wonder. The error goes like this -- message: 'Kusto::Csv::Parser<>.PrepareFields: CSV has an inconsistent number of fields per line: ', details: 'Offending record: xxxx (start position in stream: xxxx), fieldsCount: 32, currentRecordFieldCount: 31')

Comment: @Dhiraj - we will follow up in the support ticket you opened about this.